# How to get inner text in a xml tag array in php

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xpath, simplexml

So i have an xml like this:

```
<cars> 
    <brand name="Audi"> 
        <model>A1</model> 
        <model>A3</model>
        <model>A5</model> 
    </brand> 
    <brand name="Ferrari"> 
        <model>F12</model>
        <model>FF</model> 
    </brand> 
</cars>
```

And what i want is to convert this to this: $cars['Audi'][0]['A1'] and so, but i don't know how to get the inner text there is into the  tags (example: F12). I'm trying with simplexml by the way!

So, for now i'm doing this:

```
$doc = new SimpleXmlElement($xml, LIBXML_DTDLOAD); 
$brands = $doc->xpath('//brand[@model="Audi"]');
$model_1 = $brands[0]->model[0];
```

And of course nothing happens...

Comment: Show us what you're tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = '<cars> 
            <brand name="Audi"> 
                <model>A1</model> 
                <model>A3</model>
                <model>A5</model> 
            </brand> 
            <brand name="Ferrari"> 
                <model>F12</model>
                <model>FF</model> 
            </brand> 
        </cars>';

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($doc->children() as $brand) {
    foreach ($brand->children() as $model) {
        $cars[(string)$brand->attributes()->name][] = (string)$model;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($cars);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<cars> 
    <brand name="Audi"> 
        <model>A1</model> 
        <model>A3</model>
        <model>A5</model> 
    </brand> 
</cars>
```

---

```
$cars = simplexml_load_file("cars.xml"); // root tag cars
// echo $cars->brand[0]['name'];
foreach ($cars->brand[0]->model as $model) {
echo $model;
}
```

I have made this example even more cool:

```
<?php
echo "<head><style>html,body{padding:0;margin:0;background-color:black;text-align:center;}.ul{border-bottom:10px dashed #555555;width:50%;margin-left:25%;margin-right:25%;list-style-type:none;box-shadow:0px 0px 2px gold;}.li{font-size:100px;background-color:silver;color:white;font-family:arial;text-shadow:1px 1px black;}.li:nth-child(even){background-color:yellow;}</style></head><body>";

$cars = simplexml_load_file("cars.xml"); // root tag cars
// echo $cars->brand[0]['name'];

foreach($cars->brand as $brand) {
  echo "<div class='ul'>";
  foreach($brand->model as $model) {
    echo "<div class='li'>";
    echo $model;
    echo "</div>";
  }
  echo "</div>";
}

echo "</body>";
```

Comment: what was my answer then :D ?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
//cars/brand[@name="Audi"]/*[1]
```

Your Errors:

1. attribute matching should be `@name="Audi"`
2. `*[1]` is the first child node

Example

```
$models = $doc->xpath('//cars/brand[@name="Audi"]/*[1]');
var_dump((string)current($models));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the trick was to convert to string the  tag when the iteration and of course iterate it!

(string)$model;

that was it! i thought it was empty because the debugger didn't return me anything when i inspected it.

All your questions worked right, thank you very much!

Comment: Try using `var_dump` to inspect the output. It returns `object(SimpleXMLElement)` instead of being empty. The `(string)` in front converts it to an ordinary string.