# Pass XML Path into Function Doesn't Return Value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following PHP function that takes an XML Path after the -> for my SimpleXML.

```
function parseRecipeData($xmlPath) {
    global $db_recipe_type;
    global $db_recipe_filename;
    global $xml;

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($db_recipe_filename);
    // var_dump($xml);

    // Get data from XML Field
    $requestedInfo = $xml->$xmlPath;
    //var_dump($requestedInfo);

    return $requestedInfo;
}
```

My problem is that PHP line #1 returns nothing, while PHP line #2 returns the XML Value. Note that `$recipeSize = "batch->attributes()->quantity";` is defined at the top of my application and should be a global scope. My XML tree is below the rest of this code.

1: `<?php echo parseRecipeData($recipeSize); ?>`

2: `<?php echo $xml->batch->attributes()->quantity; ?>`

**XML Structure**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE recipe>
<recipe>
  <batch quantity="2.13 gal"/>
</recipe>
```

Can anyone see why one PHP line would return a function and wouldn't considering they should resolve to the same code?

Comment: This is not how it's done. You'd have to `eval()` to get `"batch->attributes()->quantity";` parsed as part of the object "path" (which is an irky approach).

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504544/how-to-get-inner-text-in-a-xml-tag-array-in-php/14504925#14504925

Comment: @Pekka웃 you meany I would need `eval()` to pass that string into my function like that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how it works: You'd have to run `eval()` to turn the string "batch->attributes()->quantity" into something that you can use. This is an irky approach at best.

It would be more elegant if you would e.g. use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) and pass the function an XPath string. Looking at the docs, the string should look something like so:

```
/recipe/batch@quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another function:

```
function getRecipeData() {
    global $db_recipe_type;
    global $db_recipe_filename;
    global $xml;

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($db_recipe_filename);

    return $xml;
}
```

Usage:

```
getRecipeData()->batch['quantity'];
```

The other solution is like Pekka suggest to xpath query it.